# How can I identify a code in a text field and report on it?

Tags: text

I am sorry about this very basic question but I am very new to Salesforce.

I have a text field in which users report a status (RLR1, RLR2, RLR3) together with a free text, e.g.

> RLR1 Alert since customer is not solvable.

I now need a report sorted based on this code. How can I do this?
Thanks

Comment: text field, text area (long) field?

Comment: User summary type report and use filters to get appropriate data.

Comment: @crop1645 it's a Text Area(255) field.

Comment: @Giene I can add an additional filter in my report to filter records with RLR1 for example in this field but what I need is to show ALL records of this report and regroup them according to the status RLR1, RLR2 in this specific long text field etc.

Comment: Is the code always at a fixed position and of a fixed Len within the text area 255 field?  Are the codes of a predictable pattern?  If so, a formula field could be the answer

Comment: @crop1645 I could ask users to enter the code at the very beginning of the text field or at the very end. E.g. "RLR1 status because blabla...". But I can't change the type of the field or add another one as this is a very big org and I'm not authorized to do so.

Comment: I would still recommend to them that they add a pick list for the Code part and keep the existing for the free text description. See what they say

Answer (score 0):

Peter

The normal solution to this problem would be to create a custom formula field that extracted the `RLRx` code from the text area(255) field into a separate field that you could then group and summarize on in a standard SFDC report. For example, if the code was always at the beginning of the text field, the formula field would be `LEFT(textfield__c,4)`

But you say you can't create new fields in your org... :-(

If your org uses after market reporting products like DrawLoop or Conga Composer, those tools allow their respective Excel templates to post process the SFDC report output, including extracting the RLRx code into a new column and then pivoting on that new column, yielding a nice summary report in Excel

Another option would be Microsoft's PowerQuery for Excel (which I believe is free) that can also pull from a Salesforce report and do all sorts of manipulations with the resulting data.  If you use Office 365, the PowerQuery workbook can be placed on a shared server (cloud) accessible to all who need to generate the report